# Lookup a tag by field symbol in Go

Tags: go, reflection

Given a structure with fields I'd like to lookup tag value for particular field symbolically (without providing field name as string).

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    Foo string `tag:"val"`
}
entity := MyStruct{}
tagVal := getTag(&entity.Foo) // the function would return "val" for Foo field
```

I'd like to implement a `getTag` function that would return tag value for a given field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer to field value does no contain any information about owner structure, that's a different way of indirection, so having only a pointer field value is not enough to solve the problem.

One solution could be to use pointer to owner structure together with pointer to the field in that structure, iterate fields of that structure value with reflection until the address of iterated field matches given field value pointer.

https://play.golang.org/p/kaPQ9HF9wAK

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type MyStruct struct {
        Foo string `tag:"val"`
    }
    entity := MyStruct{}
    tagVal := getTag(&entity, &entity.Foo)
    fmt.Println(tagVal) // val
}

func getTag(structPtr, fieldPtr interface{}) string {
    sf, ok := structFieldByValPtr(structPtr, fieldPtr)
    if !ok {
        return ""
    }
    return sf.Tag.Get("tag")
}

func structFieldByValPtr(structPtr, fieldPtr interface{}) (reflect.StructField, bool) {
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(structPtr))
    t := v.Type()

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        fv := v.Field(i)
        ft := t.Field(i)

        if fv.Addr().Interface() == fieldPtr {
            return ft, true
        }

        if ft.Anonymous {
            sf, ok := structFieldByValPtr(fv.Addr().Interface(), fieldPtr)
            if ok {
                return sf, true
            }
        }
    }

    return reflect.StructField{}, false
}
```